# How to insert data partial from select statement in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data partially from select statement..
For example..

I have one table named movie..here's the fields :

```
-id_movie
-tittle
-studio
-time
```

And another table named reservation.. here's the fields :

```
-id_reservation
-tittle
-studio
-time
-seat_1
-seat_2
```

So, I want to insert value of tittle, studio, and time into reservation table that getting from select statement from movie table. But I'm a little bit confuse about another field in reservation table (id_reservation, seat_1, seat_2).. They're actually don't exist in the first table (movie table)
so how to write the query?

any simple example would be very helpful

thank you

Comment: can you give your `CREATE` scripts of your both tables

Comment: where do you get the values for `seat_1` and `seat_2` from? Or should they be left blank?

Answer (score 2):

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO reservation(tittle,studio,time)
            SELECT tittle,studio,time FROM movie";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO reservation (
    tittle, 
    studio, 
    time
)
SELECT  tittle, 
        studio, 
        time 
FROM movie;
```

But you better not have NOT NULL on the columns you leaving without values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want mysql query then:

```
"INSERT INTO reservation(tittle,studio,time)  
     SELECT tittle,studio,time from movie";
```

Answer (score 0):

First do a SELECT from "movie" to obtain the fields you need from that table. 
You will have the fields you need stored in 3 variables, say $title, $studio, $time.

As per the table reservation, the field id_reservation should be the PK so set it to autoincrement. You don't have to insert that value as it does it automatically in every insert.
The fields seat_1 and seat_2 will depend on other facts than the data you get from the first table. You should obtain the free seats (I guess there is another table with the total amount of seats), and select 2 using some kind of logic (for example, that they are next to each other)

So in the end, the INSERT query for the table reservation should look like

```
"INSERT INTO reservation (title, studio, time, seat_1, seat_2) VALUES('$title', '$studio', '$time', $seat_1, $seat_2)");
```